# "Whatever is Left" in a CSS layout

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

I have 4 elements inside a container element. The container element will have its height set to 100% of the browser window. The 4 inner elements will appear vertically stacked on each other (as normal). The first two elements and the last element should have a "natural" height (ie: enough to fit their contents). The 3rd element should expand to fill the space available in the container, after the other 3 eat all they need to.

So, it would look something like this:

[image: CSS Stacked Elements]

I cannot set explicit heights for Element-1, Element-2, or Element-4, nor do I know the height of the Container. I don't know the natural height of Element-3 either; I plan on using `overflow-scroll` if it gets larger then what's available. I've added spacing between the elements for illustration, but there will be spacing (margins/padding) between the real elements too.

How do you achieve this using HTML/CSS? If compromises have to be made to get a decent layout, I'll consider them. Bonus points if the technique also applies horizontally (which I've needed on occasion).

Comment: Nice visual.  It helps immensely.

Comment: What is element-4? is it content or just style?

Comment: All elements, including element-4, will have content in them.

Comment: After re-reading the question I've realized that I misread element-3 as element-4. And it sounds to me like you're just trying to create a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), which is different from what you've described, but may result in the layout you're after.

Comment: zzzzBov: The sticky footer (Element-4) is part of that, but the real trick is getting so Element-3 doesn't extend into it. The technique you linked to depends on a known/set height for the footer, which I don't have for Element-4.

Comment: @Craig Walker, again: javascript is necessary. CSS will get you most of the way there, but you need a programming language to do the number crunching to get the layout you're after.

Comment: Yup, it certainly looks that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, great visual.

Secondly.. would a javascript solution be out of the question?

**Update**

This was just intended to be a sample, but I have updated the code to appease some of the more picky people out there.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsZAV/9/

Comment: @Dutchie432 Looks nice, only thing is recalculating on resize then. And on every AJAX call probably or whatever dynamic content is there.

Comment: @Dutchie 1. The margin value is incorrect. Vertical margins collapse. 2. You forgot to include the borders into the calculation. Use outerHeight() instead of height(). 3. The OP wants the layout to stretch 100% vertically.

Comment: @Dutchie Also, the CENTER element? Really?

Comment: Oh come on .. I just threw up center as a way to center it.. obviously you could encapsulate it in a div.

Comment: @Dutchie No, you wouldn't. You would just set `margin:0 auto` on the `#mainContainer` DIV.

Comment: WOW you're awesome. This is just a sample to get the poster going in the right direction.

Comment: @Dutchie So your thinking was: This is just a sample, so I'll use CENTER which is deprecated for more then 10 years and its usage is strongly recommended against? And if not that, I'll wrap it inside another DIV just to center it, which is also recommended against? Bad practices should be avoided, **especially** in samples.

Comment: @Dutchie In your updated sample ( http://jsfiddle.net/tsZAV/5/ ), the calculation is off, which results in the container DIV being to high and a vertical scrollbar being shown. 1. You have to set `marginHeight` to 25 because vertical margins collapse. 2. You have to set `padding:0` on the BODY element to clear the padding. 3. You have to take the border of the container into consideration when setting the container height. After applying those three changes, the calculation will be correct - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tsZAV/6/

Comment: @Dutchie432: JS certainly isn't out of the question... but if it came down to that I'd probably lean towards some other layout instead. +1 for a working solution though.

Comment: @Dutchie Also, `margin:0 auto` to make it work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/tsZAV/7/

Comment: @Šime Vidas: This is a SAMPLE. I did not test it in 400 different browsers. I view it in my browser and it works just fine. The calculation can be adjusted via CSS to fit each Browser.

Comment: @Dutchie The calculation should be correct. What difference does it make if it's a sample or not? The correct `marginHeight` is 25, not 40. (Adjacent vertical margins collapse.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that make this impossible in pure css.

1. The browser window could be shorter than the dynamic height of the first 3 elements.
2. There is no way to force an element to take up the rest of the container's height.
3. CSS is a document styling language, not a programming language. Think of writing CSS as a set of guidelines that the page should try to follow, rather than a way of explicitly setting sizes (although you can explicitly set sizes).

This is relatively simple to do with JavaScript resizing the fourth element. You'll have to listen for a `resize` event so that the fourth element gets sized accordingly. Also, you'll want to set a `min-height` value for element-4, in case there isn't enough space for the fourth element.

Comment: I doubt it's impossible to do in pure CSS, just that it's impossible to do in pure CSS that many still-relevant-but-incredibly-outdated browsers support.

Comment: @reisio, i've read the entire specs for CSS2&3, there's no standardized way of doing `height: fill` or similar. There may be a browser-specific way of doing something like that, but at that point you're better off setting a min-height, and letting javascript handle it.

Comment: I was thinking of the table(-*) values for display, offhand.